# react native bundle sha-1 for file not computed(unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle)

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) tutorial for creating new rn app.after installations when I try to run my just created app I'm getting this error:

> unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle

after lot's of research about this lead me to do bundle
but when I do bundle with this command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

I'm getting this error:

> SHA-1 for file c:\Users\mehrdad\Desktop\WorkSpace\ReactNative\awesomeproject\index.js is not computed

And my problem still exists

```
"react": "16.4.1",

"react-native": "0.56.0",

"windows 8.1"
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I updated `react-native-cli` and the problem disappeared :

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: Thanks.Apparently problem have been solved in new version.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well.

Comment: Fixed for me. The error showed up originally when using `fastlane` to do `gradle(task: 'assemble')`

Comment: Fixed it for me too <3

Comment: Was able to fix it with npm i -g react-native-cli --force command...Thanks..

Answer (score 17):

Ran into the same issue when using the react-native to run the mentioned command directly.

Running the same command with npx solved it for me. Try running the below and see if that helps.

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Comment: You saved my day. I almost spent more than 4 hours. Thanks Man

Answer (score 10):

For me, I was using `react-native start` when I normally use `npx react-native start`, using `npx` fixed the issue!

Answer (score 9):

My issue was that I tried to `require` a file with the proper path but incorrect capitalization.

Answer (score 6):

If the error also includes metro-bundler not working, try restart your system. I restarted my system and it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Again start metro bundle
 i.e react-native start and then working

Answer (score 3):

Just terminate your current Metro bundler process and start a new Metro bundler. Worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```

update your react native CLI globally.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

my issue was that my `--entry-file app.js` was supposed to be `--entry-file App.js`.

I corrected that and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For completion, I had the same issue. In my case, it was due to the location of the project having a symlink as one of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Running `npm run android` instead of `react-native start` fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the above suggestions worked for me. Going to src -> app -> App.js and changing App.js to app.js fixed the issue.[[image: side panel1]