# SHA-1 for file .png (.png) is not computed (using Expo-CLI)

Tags: react-native, expo

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^34.0.3",
    "firebase": "^6.3.4",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**App.json**

```
"sdkVersion": "34.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
```

how to resolve this as --reset-cache have no effect and Also the error is shown for that file which is not even the part of the project.

I also find same type of issue on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826728/react-native-bundle-sha-1-for-file-not-computedunable-to-load-script-from-asset?rq=1)
but that is for react-native-cli in which upgrading react-native-cli resolved the issue.

I tried to upgrade expo-cli but nothing happen things remain the same.

I hope I am able to explain the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try `expo start -c`

It should be executed with the correct method of execution.