# Handle local image into application - got sha1 error

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to make a notes app with attached images.
When the user adds an image I save it to my server and then save the path to the image in my server.

```
{this.state.img ? <Image
              style={stylesCP.image}
              source={{ uri: require(this.state.img)}}
            ></Image> : null}
```

While the img state contains: /Users/myUser/Study/React-Native/Note/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/images/1_3_2021_5_06_08_PMimg.jpg

And I'm getting this error:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

SHA-1 for file /Users/myUser/Study/React-Native/Note/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/images/1_3_2021_5_06_08_PMimg.jpg (/Users/myUser/Study/React-Native/Note/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/images/1_3_2021_5_06_08_PMimg.jpg) is not computed

Can anyone help me with that please?

Answer (score 2):

you needs to specify the local image syntax and path correctly like so,
try this let me know

```
class ImageExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      img: require('../../Assests/Images/1_3_2021_5_06_08_PMimg.jpg'),
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {
          this.state.img ?
          <Image
            source={this.state.img}
          />
          : null
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageExample;
```

Comment: This is doesn't work even when I write this:
<Image
            style={stylesCP.image}
            source={require("/Users/MyUser/Study/React-Native/Note/WebApplication1/WebApplication1/images/1_3_2021_5_06_08_PMimg.jpg")}
          ></Image>

Comment: I added one example . Try that let me know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51826728/react-native-bundle-sha-1-for-file-not-computedunable-to-load-script-from-asset