# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (react native 0.64.0, xcode 12.4)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode12

After upgrading React Native from 0.63.4 to 0.64.0, I've got following error. This only happens when I want to archive app, when I'm building and starting app on emulator, everything works fine.

[image: Error]

I know that this topic isn't new but I've already tried everything and nothing helps. Hope somebody will know how to fix it, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the "Potential causes:"?

Comment: Also this question seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51826728/14351818